# Get List of Objects That User Shares a Group With

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-active-directory

I'm using Entity Framework. I have a list of Requests. Each Request has a list of Approvals. When a user is logged in, I need to find a list of Requests that the user is involved in (is a member of a group who's GroupId is in an Approval in the Request). To figure out which groups a user belongs to, I call `CheckGroups(groupIds)` where groupIds is a list of strings I want to check, and it returns a list of strings that the user belongs to. This method is relatively slow, as it has to make a network call (it's an Azure Active Directory Graph API call). Also, groupIds has a max size of 20.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Request> Requests;
    public virtual DbSet<Approval> Approvals;
}

public class Request
{
    public int RequestId;
    // several irrelevant properties
    public virtual ICollection<Approval> Approvals;
}

public class Approval
{
    public int ApprovalId;
    public int RequestId;
    // several irrelevant properties
    public string GroupId;
}
```

This is what I'm thinking so far:

1. Go through `MyDbContext.Approvals` and get list of all unique `GroupId`.
2. Pass 20 of them to `CheckGroups()`.
3. Store returned strings to a list.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until all unique groups sent.
5. Go through `MyDbContext.Approvals` and if the `GroupId` matches the list from step 3, add the `RequestId` to a list.
6. Get list of all Requests that have a `RequestId` in the list from step 5.

Seems really inefficient. Is there a better way to do this? Trying to minimize time (database calls for entity framework and calls to `CheckGroups()` are the bottlenecks). As the database grows larger (more Requests added with multiple Approvals per Request) this could get ugly.

Comment: Can you return groups for specific user?

Comment: Ah, didn't think I could, but I just checked and it looks like I can. The CheckGroups function (its actually CheckMemberObjects, I just renamed it for simplicity) takes 20 at a time, but I can also call the GetMemberObjects function, which will return a list of groups the user belongs to, up to 2046 of them. I'll need to check if that's enough (I suspect it will be, 2046 is a lot).

Comment: If you can do that, then you can use `requests.Where(r => r.Approvals.Any(a => userGroups.Contains(a.GroupId)))` . It will be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, the network request has the most effect for the performance. Especially, you would repeat the request until the groups sent.

I also suggest that you get all the groups belonged users first then compare the groups locally to see whether the performance was improved.

Or you may consider making your request asynchronously to improve the performance of network request.

Comment: I did your idea. Got all groups (I didn't think there was a way to do this but I did find a call) and compared locally. thanks!